# How to send data from input datetimepicker.js to jsp and save this data in db

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, jsp, web-applications

It means that, I enter value into input field 07/05/2015 7:19 PM how I can save this value (using java, jsp, servlet, MySql) it means on reload I do not lose my value. Or recommend me something else

Answer (score 0):

You can send it as request parameter or hidden field. before the page submit you can store the value into hidden variable and then submit.

provide the value from the datepicker

in the action class/servlet you can get this value by

String dateString =request.getParameter("dateValue");